# centos 6.9 cpanel php 5.6 upgrade to php7

Tags: php, package, upgrade, cpanel, centos6

i have centos 6.9 server which need to upgrade php current version is 5.6

before go remove I try  rpm -qa | grep php and the result is this

so i think remove all of this will direct affect system
yum remove cpanel-php56*

I'm going to use php70 source installation

could you guys help me which packages should I remove before  install php7 and will there be any chance's to install php 7 with out remove all of those  packages

```
root@server [~]# rpm -qa | grep php
cpanel-php56-Horde-Imap-Client-2.29.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Secret-2.0.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-trean-1.1.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Iceland-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Ukraine-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Role-1.0.1-3.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-HTML-Template-IT-1.3.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-sourceguardian-10.0-1.cp1158.x86_64
cpanel-php56-Horde-Vfs-2.3.2-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-IMAP-1.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Mail-2.6.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Template-2.0.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-imp-6.2.14-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-SOAP-0.13.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Austria-0.1.5-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Mail-Autoconfig-1.0.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Text-Figlet-1.0.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Autoloader-2.1.2-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Tree-2.0.4-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Rdo-2.0.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-horde-lz4-1.0.10-1.cp1158.x86_64
cpanel-php56-Horde-Log-2.2.0-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Service-Twitter-2.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Spain-0.1.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-USA-0.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-CssMinify-1.0.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Console-Table-1.1.5-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-5.6.30-1.cp1158.x86_64
cpanel-php56-Horde-Browser-2.0.12-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Css-Parser-1.0.10-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Argv-2.0.12-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-ElasticSearch-1.0.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Form-2.0.13-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Mail-Mime-1.8.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Romania-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Finland-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Cache-1.5.6-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Auth-2.1.12-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Compress-2.1.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Routes-2.0.5-1.cp1158.noarch
suphpselector-1-7.x86_64
cpanel-php56-Horde-Share-2.0.10-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Lock-2.1.2-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Itip-2.1.2-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Queue-1.1.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Rpc-2.1.7-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-kronolith-4.2.16-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-0.21.8-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Services-Weather-1.4.7-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Brazil-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Czech-0.1.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Australia-0.2.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Yaml-2.0.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Socket-Client-2.1.1-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Log-1.12.7-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-XML-SVG-1.1.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Exception-2.0.8-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Date-2.3.0-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-Socket-1.0.14-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Alarm-2.2.7-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Text-Diff-2.1.2-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Xml-Wbxml-2.0.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-View-2.0.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Prefs-2.7.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Feed-2.0.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Crypt-Blowfish-1.1.1-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Controller-2.0.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-SyncMl-2.0.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-HTTP-Request-1.4.4-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Sweden-0.1.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-SanMarino-0.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Portugal-0.1.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Denmark-0.1.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Pack-1.0.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-HTTP-WebDAV-Server-1.0.0RC8-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Auth-SASL-1.0.6-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-XML-RPC-1.5.5-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Serialize-2.0.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Injector-2.0.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Text-Flowed-2.0.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-SMTP-1.6.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Kolab-Format-2.0.4-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Mime-2.9.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Mime-Viewer-2.1.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Oauth-2.0.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-SessionHandler-2.2.7-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-content-2.0.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-nag-4.2.9-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-XML-Parser-1.3.4-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Russia-0.1.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Ireland-0.1.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Venezuela-0.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Slovenia-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-Sieve-1.3.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-File-Fstab-2.0.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-HTTP-1.4.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-ioncube-5.1.2-1.cp1158.x86_64
cpanel-php56-Horde-Group-2.1.1-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Token-2.0.9-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Stream-1.6.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Xml-Element-2.0.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-SpellChecker-2.1.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Stream-Wrapper-2.1.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Perms-2.1.7-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-History-2.3.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Date-Parser-2.0.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Crypt-2.7.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Constraint-2.0.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-horde-5.2.10-4.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-timeobjects-2.1.2-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Mail-1.2.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-webmail-5.2.14-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-EnglandWales-0.1.5-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Netherlands-0.1.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Croatia-0.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-JavascriptMinify-1.1.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-UserAgent-Detect-2.5.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-DB-1.7.14-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-FTP-1.3.7-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php-composer-1.1.1-7.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Smtp-1.9.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Translation-2.2.1-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Nls-2.2.0-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-ingo-3.2.10-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Stream-Filter-2.0.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Cache-2.5.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Kolab-Session-2.0.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Imsp-2.0.5-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Http-2.1.6-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Service-Facebook-2.0.5-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Core-2.23.0-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-DNS2-1.4.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-UNO-0.1.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Serbia-0.1.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-PEAR-Command-Packaging-0.3.0-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-phpmyadmin-4.0.10.18-7.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Text-Filter-2.3.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Compress-Fast-1.1.1-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-HashTable-1.2.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Timezone-1.0.11-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Dav-1.1.3-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-XML-Serializer-0.20.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Germany-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Norway-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Idna-1.0.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-MDB2-2.4.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Url-2.2.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Pdf-2.0.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Db-2.3.1-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Data-2.1.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-ListHeaders-1.2.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-turba-4.2.14-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Net-URL-1.0.15-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Japan-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Italy-0.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-File-1.4.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Console-Color-1.0.3-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Util-2.5.7-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-LoginTasks-2.0.7-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Editor-2.0.4-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Icalendar-2.1.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Image-2.3.5-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Cli-2.0.6-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-mnemo-4.2.10-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-PHPdotNet-0.1.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Turkey-0.1.1-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-File-Find-1.3.2-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-zendopt-7.0.0-1.cp1158.x86_64
cpanel-php56-Horde-Notification-2.0.4-1.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Date-1.4.7-2.cp1158.noarch
cpanel-php56-Horde-Support-2.1.5-1.cp1158.noarch
```

Comment: ask it on serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks mate I just need know can i install php7 on this server or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use EasyApache4 from the WHM interface. It will install php 5.5.x, php 5.6.x, php 7.x and even php 7.1.x. Then using MultiPHP from the same WHM interface you can customize the default php version on the server and also different php vesions for your cPanel users.

Do not manually install or delete php packages on the server or default php packages provided by cPanel. You risk to break stuff on the server which will lead to functionality issues.